# How to remove class value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can I remove a class property in html using jquery?

If the element is `class = "item active"` on the next clone in jQuery how can I remove the active word?

Here's the Jquery Code

```js
(function() {

  $('#itemslider').carousel({
    interval: 3000
  });
}());

(function() {
  $('.carousel-showmanymoveone .item').each(function() {
    var itemToClone = $(this);
    var allcase = $('#cases').val();

    for (var i = 1; i < allcase - 1; i++) {
      itemToClone = itemToClone.next();


      if (!itemToClone.length) {
        itemToClone = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }


      itemToClone.children(':first-child').clone()
        .addClass("cloneditem-" + (i))
        .appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
}());
```

Comment: .clone().removeClass('active')

Comment: look at removeClass() function

Comment: thank you everyone, yes i did try that code before i asked but i don't know where to place it hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#your-element-id").removeClass('the-class-you-want-to-remove')`

Example:

```js
// Try to comment this line
$("#my-div").removeClass('active');
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: grey;
}
.blue{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-div" class="item active blue">Hello, World!<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use removeClass method

```
$(".active").removeClass("active");
```

Comment: No need the dot inside removeClass('active').

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to set the new class.

```
jQuery('selector').attr('class', 'item');
```

Comment: Good, but this will remove other classes. Ex: `class="item active blue"`, When use your method this witll be `class="item"`. note that `blue` class was removed